# how to user jsonb_set on php while update json field on postgress

Tags: php, json, postgresql, pdo, sql-update

I have the table `my_table` and have field `id,name (varchar), properties (jsonb)` on Postgres.

The `name` field already inserted and now i want to add some data to the properties field.

```
<?php
         global $dbh;
        $queryUpdate = "UPDATE my_table set 
        properties=jsonb_set(coalesce(properties,'{}'),'{token_approval}','{$token}',true) where id=:id";
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($queryUpdate);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $idPengajuanUtama);
        try {
            $stmt->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new RuntimeException($e->getMessage() . "\r\n Function " . __METHOD__);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
?>
```

When I run the code I always get the below error.

```
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json\nLINE 1: ..._set(coalesce(properties,'{}'),'{token_approval}','asdfadsna...\n
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the query like this:

```
update my_table 
set properties = jsonb_set(
    coalesce(properties, '{}'), 
    '{token_approval}', 
    to_jsonb(:token::text)
)
where id = :id
```

Note that this allows passing the token as a query parameter rather than concatenating it in the query string.

You might find it easir to use built-in jsonb operators:

```
update my_table 
set properties = 
    coalesce(properties, '{}') 
        - 'token_approval' 
        || jsonb_build_object('token_approval', :token)
where id = :id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e92c42ec07579a5144ad60fe0ae53532)**